# Allow Android market access but not Google merchant account access

Tags: android

My company would like me to manage paid Android applications in Android Market but not have access to the linked google merchant account. This is a very reasonable request but there seems to be no way to accomplish this. According to google docs the same google account must be used for the market and merchant account therefore if I have access to one then I have access to the other.

How do other corporations deal with this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If the company uses google-apps ([see here](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html)), it can create an account for you and revoke/grant the particular service.